# How to log out of Stack Overflow using IE6

Tags: support, logout

I'm using IE6 (with all the updates). I've been a member for about six months. For the first three months, I was able to log out from my user account. Since then, I have had to rely on a fly-over hint "menu box" that pops up when I mouse over my name at the top of the page. There, I select "logout" and all is well.

Periodically, IE6 spastically doesn't get the hint and gives me nothing.

I have a weird configuration. I avoid viruses via custom level security in IE6's properties, in which I turn on/off JScript depending on the site I go to. I don't trust or want antivirus or firewall software.

This method does work. I do test cases with no AV in place, using just AV property settings, visiting the largest sources of viruses on the planet. I'm now trapped using IE6, since that's all I know. No viruses get through, though.

**Edit**
Doh, @Squillman, Thanks a Bunch!!
I tried to upvote you and mark for an answer, but I'm in that IE6 phase of oblivion.
I copied the link here and will upvote/mark as the correct answer when I get the ship righted.

Thank you!

Comment: IE6 is most assuredly **not** supported.

Comment: What is this "Log Out" you speak of?

Comment: In my programming experience, it shouldn't be too hard to make IE6 *functional*. It's just really hard to make it visually consistent with modern browsers.

Answer (score 7):

You can always use https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout

[or whichever domain corresponding to the SE site you wish to log out of]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to cookies. I find that when I browse SO in Private mode (I use Safari at home and FF 4 at work), I can't log out. I can click through, the page refreshes, but nothing has changed. Same thing when I try to log out of Google, which makes sense because my SO account is linked to my OpenId.

If your security settings don't allow SO or OpenId write access to cookies on your machine, you may well have problems logging out.